# Auto Layout: Constraints in relation to Image views and views

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

I have been trying to do this particular layout for months now and I need help with what constraints are needed.  Below is pictures of what I generally want in regards to the layout.

Portrait

https://s18.postimg.org/bunl6j5y1/Potrait.png

Landscape

https://s9.postimg.org/it9eepm27/Landscape.png

Obviously the format is not exactly correct but that is the general way of how I want it to look in portrait and landscape;  I just need to know how to add constraints in the W:Any H:Any size class so that the auto layout is universal on all devices for this particular case.

Comment: What minimum version of iOS are you targeting?  This would be petty easy with some stack views

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not understanding your question correctly, I am a beginner. But on Xcode 7 the simulator for iPhones go from 6s to 4, so whatever iOS ran the iPhone 4.  I can manage learning how to use stack views for the bottom squares as for the image view, what would you do?  Whenever I try to put these following constraints one the image view



_Vertical spacing to top layout,
Leading,
Trailing,
Bottom spacing to bottom layout_


The layout ends up looking really wacky.

Thanks!

Comment: `UIStackview` is only available in iOS 9 and later, so if you are happy for your app to only run on iOS 9 and later you can use them. https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views  You can nest stack views so, your bottom squares would be in a horizontal stack view and that stack view and your top view would be in a vertical stack view.  You can then apply appropriate constraints to that vertical stackview

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started     Tutorial is clearly given.